# FastAPI - how to declare example data for built-in type parameters

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI v0.82.0 and making a POST method like below,

```
@app.post('my_func1/add')
def func_add(id: str = Body(description='this is an id'), 
             content: str = Body(description='this is a content'))
    ...
```

With this, I can see `{"id": "string", "content": "string"}` on example value field in docs.

However, I'd like to declare an example data into each parameter `id` and `content`, not with the value `"string"`.

I know how to add an example data when the type of parameter is my own class, but have no idea when parameter is built-in type.

`Body` has `example` and `examples` attribute, so I tried

`id: str = Body(description='this is an id', example='ex_id')` and `id: str = Body(description='this is an id', examples={'normal': 'ex_id'})`. This didn't work.

Is there any way to add example data to parameters of built-in types and show it in docs?

Comment: This might be related to this, https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/5249 and seem to be fixed?

Comment: @Chris yes, I also tried `Body(example={'normal': 'ex_id'})` as well.. it didn't work.